# git : Cloned a remote repo, checked out a branch, committed a change...how to update branch on remote?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-push

This is what the remote looks like.

```
--C0--------------C4--  (master) 
      \
       --C1-C2-C3--     (lite_main)
```

Actions I took:

1. cloned the remote repo
2. checked out lite_main
3. made some changes and committed them

Results from `git reflog`:

```
27f07f4 HEAD@{0}: commit: ADDING ICON FILES TO FILE SYSTEM
445ef4b HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from master to lite_main
f9cccc0 HEAD@{2}: clone: from git@bitbucket.org:username/somerepo.git
```

Results of `git branch -a` to try to show the tracked branches:

```
* lite_main
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/lite_main
  remotes/origin/master
```

(I don't really know how to read this buy I'm guessing the only traced branch is my local origin/master is tracked to the remotes/origin/HEAD...is that right?)

Now my local repo looks like this:

```
--C0--------------C4--  (master) 
      \
       --C1-C2-C3-C5--     (lite_main)
```

How do I make my remote look like what I have locally? Will pushing lite_main to origin do it?

Comment: does your remote also has the lite_main branch

Comment: @Hermant...yes remote also has the lite_main branch...see the top diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is:

```
git push origin lite_main
```

Additionally, if you want to track the remote when creating the branch you can run the command (when creating the branch) `git checkout --track -b <local branch> <remote>/<tracked branch>`

Example `git checkout --track -b foo remote/foo`